# How to store the command output in variable and redirect to file in a same line?

Tags: bash

```
a=`cat /etc/redhat-release | awk '{print $2}' > /tmp/a.txt`
```

The above command is not redirecting the output to file.

Comment: Cargo cult programming. This is copying pieces of code from other programs, without actually knowing what the code does.

Comment: It's redirecting output to file for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A command substitution captures stdout of the command contained. When you redirect that output to a file, it's no longer on stdout, so it's no longer captured.

Use `tee` to create two copies -- one in a file, one on stdout.

```
a=$(awk '{print $2}' </etc/redhat-release | tee /tmp/a)
```

Note also:

- `cat` shouldn't be used when it isn't needed: Giving `awk` a direct handle on the input file saves an extra process, allowing a direct write from a file rather than a FIFO -- and is following a practice that will generate much larger efficiency games with programs like `sort`, `shuf`, `tail`, or `wc -c` that can use more efficient algorithms when reading from a file.
- The modern (and standard-compliant, since 1991) syntax for command substitution is `$(...)`. It nests better than the ancient backtick syntax it replaces, and use of backslashes within is less confusing.

Comment: Ty Charles!. In some case, any command contains spaces, shall I use like this "a=$(awk '{print $2}' <`get data`| tee /tmp/a)"
 (By inserting `` for command)

Comment: Not unless your command emits a filename. A regular pipeline is generally the right thing in that case.